# Link custom audience to an Adset

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am using the Facebook Marketing Api to create ads and custom audiences. How ever i cannot find a way to link the custom audiences created to a Adset.
Below is the example available in [github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/master/examples/adgroup_creation.php). For the moment i can only create Adsets with Interest and Geo locations.

As show in the example below we can only target by interest and geo location.

```
$results = TargetingSearch::search(
  $type = TargetingSearchTypes::INTEREST,
  $class = null,
  $query = 'facebook');
// we'll take the top result for now
$target = (count($results)) ? $results->current() : null;
echo "Using target: ".$target->name."\n";
$targeting = new TargetingSpecs();
$targeting->{TargetingSpecsFields::GEO_LOCATIONS}
  = array('countries' => array('GB'));
$targeting->{TargetingSpecsFields::INTERESTS} = array(
    array(
        'id' => $target->id,
        'name' => $target->name,
    ),
);


$adset = new AdSet(null, $account->id);
$adset->setData(array(
  AdSetFields::NAME => 'My First AdSet',
  AdSetFields::CAMPAIGN_ID => $campaign->id,
  AdSetFields::STATUS => AdSet::STATUS_ACTIVE,
  AdSetFields::DAILY_BUDGET => '150',
  AdSetFields::TARGETING => $targeting,
  AdSetFields::OPTIMIZATION_GOAL => OptimizationGoals::REACH,
  AdSetFields::BILLING_EVENT => BillingEvents::IMPRESSIONS,
  AdSetFields::BID_AMOUNT => 2,
  AdSetFields::START_TIME =>
    (new \DateTime("+1 week"))->format(\DateTime::ISO8601),
  AdSetFields::END_TIME =>
    (new \DateTime("+2 week"))->format(\DateTime::ISO8601),
));
$adset->validate()->create();
echo 'AdSet  ID: '. $adset->id . "\n";
```

My requirement is to link a custom audience directly to Adset, for example 
AdSetFields::CUSTOMAUDIENCE => $audienceid

is this atleast possible ? If cannot how do we associate the custom audience we created with and Adset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the field custom_audiences which accepts a set of custom audiences to target. I'm not sure if the name is actually required also, however it's in all the examples:

```
$targeting->{TargetingSpecsFields::CUSTOM_AUDIENCES} = array(
  array(
    'id' => <AUDIENCE_ID>,
    'name' => <AUDIENCE_NAME>,
  ),
);
```

See the [targeting doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs/) and search for "Targeting Custom Audience & Partner Categories"

Comment: Thanks Paul, this is what i've been looking for. Some how i have missed that section in the targeting spec documentation.

Comment: Could you please share a example for java also,

I found all over the Facebook doc but didn't found.